# A found a stronghold in minecraft bedrock edition that was not under a village

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can you please explain this.

I found a stronghold in minecraft bedrock edition that was not under a village. The seed was “poop” and the coordinates were 21198, 45, -2060 (approximate).

I know strongholds in minecraft bedrock edition always generate under villages.
Here is the seed map: https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/seed-map
I can clarify the stronghold is supossed to be there.

Comment: There were no quotes in the seed

Comment: There was no endportal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A seed can't be poop. It has to be a number. You *can* type in "poop", but when you load up the world, the letters translate into numbers.
2. Strongholds don't always have to be located under villages. They can be found pretty much anywhere, under the ground, or ocean. **But** you do have a greater chance for a stronghold to be located under a village.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's turned to numbers, the seed is still "poop". Even though multiple words will probably get you the same seed saying the seed is "poop" is completely valid.